# eventlistener and dispatchevent in the same widget

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a widget which includes an event listener:

```
var MyWidget = function(parseTreeNode,options) {
this.initialise(parseTreeNode,options);
this.addEventListeners([
    {type: "tw-my-message", handler: "handleMyMessage"}
            ]);
};
```

and, in the handler of the same widget a `dispatchevent`:

```
MyWidget.prototype.handleMyMessage = function(event) { 
...
this.dispatchEvent({type: "tw-my-message",param: "myparam"});
...
```

The widget listens for the message, then passes on the same message (if required) to another widget.

Currently I have to use two similar widgets (with the same function) which listen for different messages to avoid the widget from catching its own message.

How do I prevent the widget from catching its own message?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass along the publisher of the event, and then test to make sure that the event publisher is not `this`. Pseudo code to follow:

```
MyWidget.prototype.handleMyMessage = function(event) {
    if (event.publisher === this)
        return; // bail out, I published this event

    // ...
};
```

Pseudo code for `dispatchEvent`:

```
MyWidget.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(event) {
    event.publisher = this;

    // ... loop through subscribers and notify them
};
```